# Bypass rule for administration group in rules.pl in gerrit configuration

Tags: eclipse, git, prolog, gerrit

I'm not familiar with prolog language. I've used the example number 8 of the prolog cookbook.

https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/prolog-cookbook.html#_example_8_make_change_submittable_only_if_tt_code_review_2_tt_is_given_by_a_non_author

Which code is :

```
submit_filter(In,Out) :-
    In =.. [submit | Ls],
    add_non_author_approval(Ls, R),
    Out =.. [submit | R].

add_non_author_approval(S1, S2) :-
    gerrit:commit_author(A),
    gerrit:commit_label(label('Code-Review', 2), R),
    R \= A, !,
    S2 = [label('Non-Author-Code-Review', ok(R)) | S1].

add_non_author_approval(S1, [label('Non-Author-Code-Review', need(_)) | S1]).
```

This is the rule forcing a non author code review the code before submit.

It's working as intended, but I wanted users from admin group to bypass this rule(If they are author and the +2 reviewer the submit should always be enable).

Any kind of help is appreciated.

Comment: The reason you are probably not getting answers is that 1. no one who knows gerrit hangs out here. 2. those of us that know Prolog don't want to take the time to learn gerrit to answer this. While I am sure many of us here who know Prolog could easily answer this, if we had the Prolog that defined `users from admin group` and `+2 reviewer` it would make it easier for us.

Comment: Of interest: [Gerrit Code Review - Access Controls](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/access-control.html) - Notes the type [Predefined Groups](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/access-control.html#_predefined_groups) which holds `administrators` but doesn't explain exactly how they are accessed with Prolog.

Comment: Of interest: [Gerrit Code Review - Review Labels](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/config-labels.html) - Notes `+2` in [Label: Code-Review](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/config-labels.html#label_Code-Review) but doesn't explain exactly how they are accessed with Prolog.

Comment: Since StakOverflow is not good for long discussions with questions like this, (Yes I know it has rooms, but for new people they can be confusing), if you post the question at [SWI-Prolog dicourse](https://swi-prolog.discourse.group/) I and others can possibly give more help there. You need to help us on the Gerrit concepts and we can help you on the Prolog concepts.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. i will post on SWI-Prolog discourse and see how it goes.

Comment: Still have not seen your post at SWI-Prolog discourse. We don't bite. :)