# How to merge patches in Gerrit only when there are 2 +2 in Code Review

Tags: prolog, gerrit

I need to add the patches to be merged only when there they get two +2s in the code review.

I found online that to add such rules a rules.pl file is needed.

The examples are given here but I don't know Prolog to write my own rules. https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/prolog-cookbook.html

I am using Gerrit 2.14

Comment: As I noted in the comments in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57622412/1243762) perhaps you should try asking at  [SWI-Prolog dicourse](https://swi-prolog.discourse.group/)

Answer (score 0):

Personally I think it’s well worth learning Prolog, but if you have Gerrit 2.16 or above you could also look at the Simple Submit Rules plugin: https://gerrit.googlesource.com/plugins/simple-submit-rules/+/refs/heads/master

This implements a set of rules and also lets you add your own using Java.

Comment: Sorry. I forgot to mention that I am using Gerrit 2.14. Adding that to the question.